"add_transition() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str" : transitions python library
I just try make simple graph with transitions library :
from transitions.extensions.diagrams import HierarchicalGraphMachine
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

states = ['engoff' , 'poweron' , 'engon' , 'FCCActions' #'emgstatus' , "whevent" , 'new data receive'
              ,{'name' : 'cores',
                'final': True,
                'parallel' : [{ 'name' : 'mapeng', 'children': ['maploaded', {"name": "update", "final": True}],
                                'initial' : 'maploaded',
                                'transitions': [['delay', 'maploaded', "update"]]},
                    {
                     'name' : 'EAA' , 'children': ['newdata', {"name": "done!", "final": True}], #environment analayser
                     'initial' : 'newdata', 
                     'transitions': [['Analaysing', 'newdata', 'done!']]
                  },{
                     'name' : 'FAI' , 'children': ['newdata', {"name": "done!", "final": True}],
                     'initial' : 'newdata',
                     'transitions': ['CalculateandLearning', 'newdata', 'done!']
                  }]
              }
            ]


transitions = [['flightcommand', 'engon', 'FCCActions'],
                   ['poweroff-command', 'engon', 'engoff'],
                   ['init', 'engoff', 'poweron'],
                   ['engstart-command', 'poweron', 'engon'],
                   ['startservice', 'poweron', 'cores']]

m = HierarchicalGraphMachine(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="engoff", show_conditions=True,
                             title="Mermaid", auto_transitions=False)
m.init()

I just make some change in this example but I got Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../3.transitions/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    m = HierarchicalGraphMachine(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="engoff", show_conditions=True,
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\diagrams.py", line 137, in __init__
    super(GraphMachine, self).__init__(
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\markup.py", line 61, in __init__
    super(MarkupMachine, self).__init__(
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\nesting.py", line 407, in __init__
    super(HierarchicalMachine, self).__init__(
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.add_states(states)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\diagrams.py", line 230, in add_states
    super(GraphMachine, self).add_states(
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\markup.py", line 126, in add_states
    super(MarkupMachine, self).add_states(states, on_enter=on_enter, on_exit=on_exit,
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\nesting.py", line 521, in add_states
    self._add_dict_state(state, ignore, remap, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\nesting.py", line 978, in _add_dict_state
    self.add_states(state_children, remap=remap, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\diagrams.py", line 230, in add_states
    super(GraphMachine, self).add_states(
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\markup.py", line 126, in add_states
    super(MarkupMachine, self).add_states(states, on_enter=on_enter, on_exit=on_exit,
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\nesting.py", line 521, in add_states
    self._add_dict_state(state, ignore, remap, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\extensions\nesting.py", line 980, in _add_dict_state
    self.add_transitions(transitions)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py", line 1032, in add_transitions
    self.add_transition(**trans)
TypeError: add_transition() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

how can I fix this?

Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

@MichaelButscher done

This value:
    'transitions': ['CalculateandLearning', 'newdata', 'done!']

should be wrapped in another list:
    'transitions': [['CalculateandLearning', 'newdata', 'done!']]

Full source code:
from transitions.extensions.diagrams import HierarchicalGraphMachine
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

states = ['engoff' , 'poweron' , 'engon' , 'FCCActions' #'emgstatus' , "whevent" , 'new data receive'
              ,{'name' : 'cores',
                'final': True,
                'parallel' : [{ 'name' : 'mapeng', 'children': ['maploaded', {"name": "update", "final": True}],
                                'initial' : 'maploaded',
                                'transitions': [['delay', 'maploaded', "update"]]},
                    {
                     'name' : 'EAA' , 'children': ['newdata', {"name": "done!", "final": True}], #environment analayser
                     'initial' : 'newdata', 
                     'transitions': [['Analaysing', 'newdata', 'done!']]
                  },{
                     'name' : 'FAI' , 'children': ['newdata', {"name": "done!", "final": True}],
                     'initial' : 'newdata',
                     'transitions': [['CalculateandLearning', 'newdata', 'done!']]
                  }]
              }
            ]


transitions = [['flightcommand', 'engon', 'FCCActions'],
                   ['poweroff-command', 'engon', 'engoff'],
                   ['init', 'engoff', 'poweron'],
                   ['engstart-command', 'poweron', 'engon'],
                   ['startservice', 'poweron', 'cores']]

m = HierarchicalGraphMachine(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="engoff", show_conditions=True,
                             title="Mermaid", auto_transitions=False)
m.init()


I found the issue by editing the library code and adding these print functions:
transitions/core.py
    def add_transitions(self, transitions):
        """Add several transitions.

        Args:
            transitions (list): A list of transitions.

        """
        print(f'{transitions=}') # Added here.
        for trans in listify(transitions):
            print(f'{trans=}') # And here.
            if isinstance(trans, list):
                self.add_transition(*trans)
            else:
                self.add_transition(**trans)

Which showed me that the error happened on this case:
transitions=['CalculateandLearning', 'newdata', 'done!']
trans='CalculateandLearning'

